# Is it true that all symmetric binary black hole mergings emit the same power, regardless of "size"?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I recently saw [this posting](https://twitter.com/LIGO/status/1058870797970952193) on Twitter:

[image]
[image]

Yet it seems to me that

1. Kepler's Law is a Newtonian statement and does not intuitively carry into a GR realm.
2. Hawking Radiation would immediately provide a *scale*, indirectly by providing a black-body temperature for the two bodies and directly through escape of a virtual proton (ie Hydrogen ion.

Am I correct, which would seem to invalidate the base claim as queried in the title here?